# Pod install is staying on "Setting up CocoaPods Master repo"

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, cocoapods, pod-install

I'm cloning a project from a git repo, but when I execute `pod install` the first line I see is "Setting up CocoaPods Master repo" and after that I can't see anything more, the console stops there.

I don't know what is happening. Anyone knows what's happening here? Why Does CocoaPods stop there?

Answer (score 282, accepted):

You could try running in verbose mode:

```
pod install --verbose
```

That'll show you what cocoa pods are up to:

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo

Cloning spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` (branch `master`)
  $ /usr/bin/git clone 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' master
  Cloning into 'master'...
```

([as suggested here)](http://www.extendi.it/blog/2013/12/02/19-cocoapods-stuck-on-pod-install)

For me the above step took quite a long time as the repo (Dec 2016) is now **1.1 GB**

Answer (score 205):

`pod install` or `pod setup` fetches whole repo with history when you first time run it. You don't need that commit history.

```
pod setup
Ctrl +C
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos 
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

It takes around 2 mins on decent network connection (4Mbps). `master` directory is around 519M big.

Comment: Awesome, I used this to fix several weird issues I was having on `pod update`, like `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`. Just had to `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods` before executing the suggested commands.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also one note, with a fresh MBP and Sierra installed, `pod repo remove master` didn't anything. I skipped to the next step and proceeded and it worked perfectly

Comment: Please mind that 'pod update' will still cause a full fetch. 'pod install' won't. Info: http://blog.cocoapods.org/Master-Spec-Repo-Rate-Limiting-Post-Mortem/

Comment: Why https://cocoapods.org/ not mention this type of install? Stop wasting tons of developers hours!

Comment: Sugested an edit for 'pod repo remove master', as it did not work for me, nor some commenters above.

Comment: If you already have done this and run into a "out-of-date" issue, you should: 'cd ~/.cocoapods/repos/master', and then do: 'git pull'

Comment: while i am doing pod init I got "LoadError - cannot load such file -- nanaimo" Error message. could you suggest any solution ?

Comment: After giving the last command it is showing this:  fatal: destination path 'master' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Comment: @iPeter remove master directory before clone eg `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/master`

Comment: confirmed working July 2017. Remember to use --no-repo-update

Comment: I had to finish with `cd PROJ_DIR; pod install --no-repo-update`

Comment: 1.4GB as of today LOL

Answer (score 54):

Try this command to track its work.

```
while true; do
  du -sh ~/.cocoapods/
  sleep 3
done
```

Comment: alternatively: `watch du -sh ~/.cocoapods`

Comment: Thanks for posting that. In the end my .cocoapods master directory ended up at 746mb. Took about 20 minutes, walk the dog, put the kettle on, or just take a nap :-)

Comment: Much more useful than just --verbose. Time for a cup of tea!

Answer (score 46):

The issue is that you haven't got command line tools installed, I believe.
Try run in terminal:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

after that download command line tools from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action)
just search for 'Command Line Tools' and download the right version for your OS.
Once you install it run in terminal:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod setup
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to install command line tools from Xcode but it doesn't appear there (I have mavericks) I also follow this steps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371925/how-to-check-if-command-line-tools-is-installed and now I could check that I have command line tools installed, but "Setting up Cocoapods Master repo" is still there when I execute "pod install" or "pod setup"

Comment: When you click the link from my post in the left-top corner in the search box type: command line tools and you have the version for maverick OS on the top.

Comment: Thanks for your help but that didn't work. I have command line tools installed and the message still appears and doesn't go forward

Comment: @Gabox Have you call sudo gem install cocoa pods and 
pod setup after you installed command line tools?

Comment: Yes I have called sudo gem install cocoapods. I solve the problem following this tutorial http://cocoafactory.com/blog/2013/02/01/troubleshooting-cocoapods-installation/ Thanks for your help

Comment: Your answer help me, you can edit your answer and put the previous link I put and I can accept your answer

Comment: you can use this way to speed up :pod install --verbose --no-repo-update

Answer (score 21):

May be this information will be helpful:

**Official answer:** http://blog.cocoapods.org/Master-Spec-Repo-Rate-Limiting-Post-Mortem/

As a result of this discussion https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4989

**Briefly:**
CocoaPods repository experiences a huge volume of fetches from GitHub and it was the problem. Changes have been available since version 1.0.0.beta.6.

Tips from this document:

```
If for whatever reason you cannot upgrade to version 1.0.0 just yet, you can perform the following steps to convert your clone of the Master spec-repo from a shallow to a full clone:

$ cd ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
$ git fetch --unshallow
```

My hack to first installation:

```
1. pod setup
2. Ctrl+C
After that I could find ~/.cocoapods/repos/ empty directory 
3. Download  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/archive/master.zip
4. unpack it to ~/.cocoapods/repos/
5. Move to project folder
6. pod install --no-repo-update
```

Today it takes near 15 minutes

Comment: I gotta commend Tina for this. This is the fastest way to solve this problem. I used it, and it's effective! lol. Posted December 1, 2016. :)

Comment: Just to be clear, when you said to unpack the folder, will it look like this :

~/.cocoapods/repos/spec-master/...

Comment: no, you should unzip it as ~/.cocoapods/repos/master (just rename) as recommend here https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/releases

Comment: am I suppose to copy the extracted files to ~/.cocoapods/repos/ directory OR am I suppose to copy to my xcode project's root directory?

Comment: You should unpack files to ~/.cocoapods/repos/master directly. After that: call "pod install --no-repo-update" in project folder

Comment: Instead of «5. Move to project folder» you could just `git init` in that place and `git remote add origin https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`

Answer (score 16):

When CocoaPods is doing that it is downloading the entire specs repo to `~/.cocoapods`. This could take a while depending on your connection. I would try doing it explicitly first with `pod setup`

Comment: Hi, I execute pod setup and the message "Setting up Cocoapods Master repo" is still there. How long could it take? I have the command line tools installed

Comment: Shouldn't be that long, but I'd give it a few minutes

Comment: Hi, it is still showing "setting up Cocoapods Master repo" and never go forward

Comment: Quoting masweb: "check ls -lta ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/.git/objects/pack/ its downloading temporary pack there".

Comment: Got to 50mb before I killed it. https://api.github.com/repos/cocoapods/cocoapods says the repo is only 42k

Comment: Tip for my fellow obsessives, building on Final Contest above: run `brew install watch` then `watch ls -lta ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/.git/objects/pack/` to monitor progress.

Answer (score 13):

Nothing above worked for me, so this is what worked:

```
pod setup
Ctrl +C
pod repo remove master
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos 
git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs master
```

Once completed it worked.

Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

What I tried and faster than clonning the repo:

1. `pod setup`
2. Ctrl +C after creating the master directory
3. Download .zip from https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs master
4. Copy the content to `~/.cocoapods/repos`
5. `pod install --no-repo-update` in my project folder

After that I finally could see the pods being installed

Good luck!

EDIT: The zip size is 144 MB (Jul 6 2017)

Answer (score 9):

I used the following 4 commands

```
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos
git clone "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs" master --depth 1
cd master
git fetch --unshallow
pod setup
```

I took time as expected, but at least I didn't have to stair at the screen wondering whats happening in the background.

Answer (score 8):

I have an alternative solution that I currently use. By changing the repository URL in Podfile to:

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
```

changes:

```
- source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
+ source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
```

Comment: what does this solution help with? please

Answer (score 6):

```
pod setup --verbose
```

I am running the above mentioned command right now but as mentioned by @Joe Blow, it shows absolutely no information on the progress.

But if you open the Activity Monitor on Mac (Task Manager on Windows?), under the 'Network' tab you will see a process named **'git-remote-https'** and it shows the size of 'Received Bytes' increasing. After downloading about 300MB it stopped and then I could see further progress in the Terminal window.

Comment: nice, thanks for sharing it. but it is weird that --verbose doesn't work for you...

Comment: actually it does print some info in the beginning but then theres a long wait involved when downloading that 300MB+ file... anyway hope it helped!

Comment: the size has gone upto 482 MB

Answer (score 5):

This happens only once.

- **Master repo has +-1GB** *(November 2016)*.
- To **track the progress** you can use **activity monitor app** and look for `git-remote-https`.
- Next time it (`pod setup` or `pod repo update`) will only fast update all spec-repos in `~/.cocoapods/repos`.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to remove the repo and re-setup it...

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
```

Comment: that's not actually an error, just a lack of information... you just only need to add --verbose when you run the command to check what is happening

Answer (score 4):

I'm monitoring the download progress by using

```
while true; 
do   
du -sh ~/.cocoapods/;   
sleep 3; 
done
```

the progress is very slow... and failed few times. 
 But somehow after increasing the git buffer limit by using this command line `git config --global http.postBuffer 2M` The download speed is improving greatly and after downloading in total 347 Mb on `./cocoapods` folder, the progress seems to stop and network activity is also stopping.
but after waiting few minutes, turn out that cocoapod is verifying and extracting the repo and makes the total size up to 853 Mb.

notes: I'm doing it on 23 Oct 2016.

Answer (score 4):

As of cocoapods 1.7.2 you can use the cdn instead of github. It's blazing fast and it won't hang. :) The cdn is default from cocopods 1.8.0 onwards.

> To use the CDN source in your Podfile:
>
> If you don't have private specs:
>
> ```
> source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
> ```
>
> If you have private specs:
>
> ```
> source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
> - source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
> + source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
> ```
>
> Doing this will break your Podfile.lock, so you are likely to need to run pod update to see the changes (be careful, this may update your Pods also).
>
> If you have a CI setup, it is recommended to cache the new repo dir as it is very small and would save even more time. With 1.7.2 it should be located at ~/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods- (yes, with a -), but we're looking to improve the naming in an upcoming release.

More info:

- [CocoaPods 1.7.2 — Master Repo CDN is Finalized!](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.7.2/)
- [CocoaPods 1.8 Beta is Here!](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.8.0-beta/)

Answer (score 1):

I Faced same problem but it work for.I executed the Pod Install Command Before 3 Hour ago after that its updated what i want.
You just need to Keep tracking the "Activity Monitor" You can see their "git remote https" or "Git" in disk tab. It will download around 330 Mb then it shows 1 GB and After some minutes it will starts installing. No need to Execute extra command.

Note : during downloading your MAC need to in continuously Active mode.If your system goes in sleep mode then CPU stop the process and you will get a error Like Add manually.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions above worked for me, I had to uninstall coacoapods, then installed a specific version before everything worked for me

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

then

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.7.5
```

now even verbose shows progress

```
$ pod setup --verbose

Setting up CocoaPods master repo

Cloning spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` (branch `master`)
  $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git --progress -- master
  Cloning into 'master'...
  remote: Enumerating objects: 295, done.        
  remote: Counting objects: 100% (295/295), done.        
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (283/283), done.        
  Receiving objects:  20% (744493/3722462), 132.93 MiB | 567.00 KiB/s
```

Answer (score 0):

Just setup the master repo, was excited to see that we have a download progress, see screenshot ;)

CocoaPods release `1.2.0` (Jan 28) fixes this issue, thanks to all contributors and Danielle Tomlinson for this release.

---

[image]

Comment: 300 megs is "fixed" ?? They need to look at NPM for some ideas.

Comment: @JaredChmielecki as the OP, I had the same issue with old CocoaPods version (during install massage always stays "Setting up CocoaPods Master repo") now we have a download progress so that we understand some download is in progress behind the scenes ;) I know the repo is getting huge, hope we get a fix about this

Answer (score 0):

**Cocoa pods - reduce wait times to 10% ( on Mac OS ) :**

1- type `pod setup` in your project folder ( first you have to be in the project folder) from terminal in Mac OS.

2- `CTRL+z` to stop after it creates master directory ( folder ) [you can see it in your cocoa pods folder location : ~/.cocoapods/repos]

3. Download .zip from

   https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs

   master branch ( its 301 MB) , Extract it . It will take approx 5-10 mins

4.Copy the content to `~/.cocoapods/repos` ( now here you only need to copy the contents inside the master folder , so make sure that master folder is created already with pod setup command )

5- once you copy it ( or I should say move , drag and drop as copying will take forever , as its very large ), you can then do `pod install --no-repo-update`
6- your pods in the pod file now will start installing 
Here is a screenshot 
[image]

Answer (score -1):

`pod setup` works and should only take 10 mins on a solid connection. After that run: `pod install --verbose` and you should see all the comments you would normally see when running a dependancy manager.

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I had solve it using the below command.

```
git clone `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git ~/.cocoapods/repos/master`
```