# pod install --no-repo-update not work

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have some repos install using Pod. I edited them manually, so I don't want to update them when install new repo in future. I use "pod install --no-repo-update" but the output:

```
Re-creating CocoaPods due to major version update.
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies ..
```

And Pod downloads all repo again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022638/pod-install-is-staying-on-setting-up-cocoapods-master-repo/39904450#39904450 follow this step

Comment: Not worked. It still downloads all repo again

Comment: yes, I also encountered this issue. Although "no-repo-update" is added on the option, it still clone the master repo.