# cocoapods pod setup --verbose not downloading

Tags: git, github, cocoapods

I am trying to install cocoapods but however when I type `pod setup --verbose` it starts downloading for a little while and then it stops downloading and my internet connection is stable, I have tried to stop it and re-install it again but the same problem

> amrs-Mac:~ amr$ pod setup --verbose
>
> Setting up CocoaPods master repo
>
> Cloning spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` (branch `master`)
>    $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --progress
>   Cloning into 'master'...
>   remote: Counting objects: 1801035, done.
>   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (453/453), done.
>   Receiving objects:   3% (70783/1801035), 14.07 MiB | 419.00 KiB/s

I checked activity monitor networks and nothing is being downloaded

Is there any fix or can I install CocoaPods any other way?

Comment: this repo is massive, so i think you need just wait

Comment: This question is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022638/pod-install-is-staying-on-setting-up-cocoapods-master-repo). Your query might've been resolved in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pod install is staying on "Setting up CocoaPods Master repo"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022638/pod-install-is-staying-on-setting-up-cocoapods-master-repo)