# Command Line Tools not working - OS X El Capitan, Sierra, High Sierra, Mojave

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, osx-elcapitan, macos-high-sierra

I just upgraded from Yosemite to El Capitan (and replicated the problem upgrading from El Capitan to Sierra), and when I try to type for example `git status` inside a terminal, I get the following error:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path
 (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

I don't have Xcode installed, never did. 
Anyone have a solution?

Comment: What does "which git" tell you?  ...and maybe "file \`which git\`"?

Comment: `which git` responds to `/usr/bin/git`, and "file `which git`" to `/usr/bin/git: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`

Comment: That sounds good.  Sorry, I don't know how xcrun is getting into this.

Comment: I had some similar problems, turns out was related to accepting the license agreement ( during the upgrade I was presented with the license dialogue but it wouldn't respond to clicks and I had to restart) once it was running again I had to start Xcode to accept the license.

Comment: I am getting error in terminal "xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools (or see `man xcode-select`)" on 10.11.5 how to fix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command Line Tools bash (git) not working - macOS Sierra final release candidate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484218/command-line-tools-bash-git-not-working-macos-sierra-final-release-candidate)

Comment: I've had to run the same command after upgrading to macOS High Sierra

Comment: Answer for macOS **Catalina** in another thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58801314/7613994

Comment: I had to run: `brew install --cask xcodes` since I'm using homebrew. After this I ran `brew outdated` and the message dissapeared

Comment: `which git` gives `/usr/bin/git`. So in effect why do a heavy xcode installation if all we need is git. Why is git not running without xcode?

Answer (score 1147, accepted):

Found the fix for the problem [here](http://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/10/01/xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-library-developer-commandline-tools-missing-xcrun/).

```
xcode-select --install
```

This will bring up a prompt to install the necessary command line tools.

Comment: Worked for me. Had this issue after upgrade to El Captain

Comment: @PascalvKooten I had the same "Finding software" problem. The only way I was able to fix it was to [download the `.dmg`](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) and manually install it.

Comment: @PascalvKooten I had the same issue. Just follow the ESultanik's advice and install the DMG, it fixed the problem immediately

Comment: @Everyone else, however I was able to run `xcode-select --install` without the "Finding software" message it still didn't work. Use the .dmg as suggested (Command Line Tools OS X 10.11 for Xcode 7.2)

Comment: I am getting error in terminal "xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools (or see `man xcode-select`)" on 10.11.5 how to fix?

Comment: This issue just popped up after upgrade to Mac OS sierra.!

Comment: Fixed on macOS Sierra. Thanks

Comment: This solution dit not help me. But after I tried `xcode-select --reset` and it helped!

Comment: @SreejithMenon Yup and FWIW the fix above does *not* install xcode automatically. Only the dev tools.

Comment: For posterity: if you see this error with `git pull` but not with `git status` and are using a remote server that is running OS X, the problem may be on the remote rather on the local. In this case, git does NOT make it obvious if the error is coming from the server or from local.

Comment: Not only did I have to install xcode but I also had to add my keys: <code>ssh-add -K</code> to get this to work

Comment: I've just upgraded to High Sierra and the solution is still valid.

Comment: If anyone runs into @PascalvKooten 's problem, my monkey brain told me to run `xcode-select --install` again even though it said it was "Finding Software"... and that worked. Yay?

Comment: I upgraded to macOS High Sierra and ran into this issue. `xcode-select --install` worked for me. Thanks!!

Comment: Regarding the "Finding Software" hanging problem on High Sierra, apparently it can be caused by not having your laptop power plugged in. :P

Comment: The issue appeared when installing macOS Mojave (Version 10.14 Beta (18A326g)) & was fixed with this solution.

Comment: Worked for me. I got the issue after updating into Black background

Comment: The problem happens after upgrading to Mojave :( too and this solution still helps for that upgrade :)

Comment: I Tried with macOS Catalina still working! thanks a lot!

Comment: @ESultanik solved my issue. My issue was caused by remove and reinstall xcode. So I think xcode-select install is not working on this case.

Comment: Worked for me. Had this issue after the latest upgrade

Answer (score 92):

If you have issues with the `xcode-select --install` command; e.g. I kept getting a network problem timeout, then try downloading the dmg at [developer.apple.com/downloads](http://developer.apple.com/downloads) (Command line tools OS X 10.11) for Xcode 7.1

Comment: A better answer IMO, since I prefer the ~400 MB footprint of the command line tools to the (last time I installed) multi GB Xcode.

Comment: I stand corrected. Where did I get the idea that it did? Perhaps that the dialog has a "Get XCode" choice and maybe I clicked that back in the Mountain Lion day. Some time or other I got all of XCode when all I wanted was the command line tools.

Comment: I had this problem, and it fixed itself just by opening xcode and trying again.  Then it added an "update" to the App Store, which is the command line tools package.

Answer (score 15):

In macOS 10.14 this issue may also occur if you have two or more versions installed. If you like xCode GUI you can do it by going into preferences - `CMD + ,`, selecting `Locations` tab and choosing version of Command Line Tools. Please refer to the attached print screen.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me when I upgraded mac os to Mojave.

Comment: It works for me. In my case, I unistalled XCode and installed XCode Beta, after that command line tools didn't work anymore. So, with this solution, it works. Thks.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. It was not set at all in my case.

Answer (score 12):

I tried the solution `xcode-select --install` but it don't help me, I update from Sierra to High and happened this, my solution:

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Answer (score 7):

Reassigning the path Xcode is configured with worked for me.

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app`

You'll then likely be prompted (after trying a command) to agree to the license agreement.

Comment: This saves a lot of time for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue after upgrading to macOS Catalina.
This didn't work for me:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Downloading and installing [Command Line Tools for Xcode 12](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_12/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_12.dmg) did it!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For me, after I've removed Xcode, I have to switch active developer path as follows:

`sudo xcode-select -s /`

Answer (score 3):

For Mojave

Uninstall Any old version of Command Line Tools:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Download and [Install Command Line Tools 10.14 Mojave](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).

Answer (score 2):

I just updated to High Sierra and I couldn't just run `xcode-select --install`. First, I had to actually install xcode from the app store. Then I ran `xcode-select --install`. Then I had to run `sudo xcodebuild -license`, agree to the terms, then I could finally run git commands again.

Answer (score 2):

Updated to High Sierra 10.13.2

**xcode-select --install** ALONE did not work for me.

1. Download X-code from app store
2. $xcode-select --install
   a. May need to update after install using *softwareupdate* in command line.  $sudo softwareupdate -i "Command Line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode-9.1"
3. $sudo xcodebuild -license

Answer (score 1):

For those also having issues with `heroku` command line tools after upgrading, I also had to do the following in my terminal:

```
xcode-select --install 
brew install heroku/brew/heroku
brew link --overwrite heroku
```

It seems the upgrade to High Sierra messed with my symlinks in addition to forcing me to reinstall xcode tools. I kept getting 'not a directory' errors:

```
▸ stat /Users/mattymc/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: not a directory  
▸ fork/exec /Users/mattmcinnis/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: not a directory
```

Hope that saves someone an hour :)

Answer (score 1):

After update to macOS 10.13.3

After updating do macOS 10.13, I had to install 
**"Command Line Tools (macOS 10.13) for Xcode 9.3"**
downloaded from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded mac os to macOS High Sierra - 10.13.3 and faced a similar issue while trying to install watchman (with command - brew install watchman).

ran the command: xcode-select --install, then ran "brew install watchman" - Everything works fine!

Answer (score 1):

For the most recent version Mojave version 10.14.1, I use

solved by downloaded from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ " login by apple id, and download

> Command line tool newest stable version.dmg

That makes everything work

the old answer

```
xcode-select --install
```

doesn't work for me.

Comment: This solved the issue for me.  Note, the issue I had when running `xcode-select --install` was a popup about not being able to contact the update server.  As of writing this, the only download in the link mentioned above for Mojave users is a beta titled "Command Line Tools (macOS 10.14) for XCode 10.1 Beta 2"

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

Work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Even if you do xcode-select --install it was not fixing that for me as it showed some network error. The problem was that it could not connect to the app store. I did the following to fix it.

1. Open keystore
2. Go to system root and select certificates.
3. Open digicert high assurance EV.
4. Expand the trust section, mark it as never trust.
5. Restart system now repeat step 1, 2, 3. and mark the trust policy as
   back to use system defaults.

Your app store should work now and you should be able to run xcode-select --install

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It might benefit with some explanation why you tried this and why it would work.

Comment: It is already written in the first line. The above solutions were not working for me. So after some googling I tried this. No need for extra expatiation