# Invalid active developer path error after upgrading to El Capitan

Tags: xcode, git

I ran into this error trying to push to git, when I typed git init.

> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path
>   (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

I tried the following solutions.

```sh
xcode-select —install
sudo xcode-select -switch
sudo xcode-select —install
brew doctor
brew update
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command Line Tools not working - OS X El Capitan/macOS Sierra/macOS High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893412/command-line-tools-not-working-os-x-el-capitan-macos-sierra-macos-high-sierra)

Comment: For Xcode 11.3, the following link is what needs to be downloaded. https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.3/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_11.3.dmg

Answer (score 237, accepted):

This is all you need to do:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Works for Sierra too

Comment: Works for High Sierra too

Comment: What does running `xcode-select --install` actually do / how does the license check work? I checked the `md5` of one of the covered executables (in my case `make`) and it's the same before and after running `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: Works for Mojave, too!

Comment: `xcode-select` - Manages the active developer directory for Xcode and BSD tools.

`--install` - Opens a user interface dialog to request automatic  installation of the command line developer tools. All this was taken directly from the BSD General Commands Manual (`man xcode-select`)

Comment: Works for Catalina, too!

Comment: This command will update/install the latest version of Xcode developer tools for your Mac. It should generalise to many problems similar to this one, and should generally work whenever the problem arises on many, especially the most recent MacOS upgrades. My vim plugin N-vimR stopped working, and doing this fixed that too.

Comment: If I could only update this answer after every MacOS upgrade.

Answer (score 41):

You can select command line tools from the XCode Preferences shown in the screenshot below.

You will get a prompt for password.

[image]

Comment: I moved my XCode to another ssd. After that I got the error message when trying to use git. Your solution is very quick and solved the problem!

Comment: I had 2 of the same option/version/id in this field, chose first one instead of selected second one, and it worked (I previously updated xcode from appstore as opposed to my initial manual DL installation, guess this is what messed it up after a simple react native library installation/linkage)

Comment: Yes, you are right, in your case maybe there are two command line tools and react native is looking for an installed tool which is not selected in Xcode. Btw I'm happy  that you solved the issue

Comment: Happy to hear, Rene! Isn't it amazing to get reply on my 4 years old answer

Comment: how do I get to this menu? I can't find "Locations" or "Command line tools" in preferences.

Comment: @CalebStanford Open Xcode and pressed " ⌘ , " it will open Settings and Second last is tab is Locations

Answer (score 25):

1)

try typing in "`xcode-select -print-path`" and see if the path you see is the path you're expecting for your current Xcode version.

2)

If you go to:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

(you'll need to sign in with your Apple Developer account)

Once there, you'll see links for "Command Line Tools".  It sounds like you need to [install MacOS 10.11 Command Line Tools for Xcode 7](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.11_for_Xcode_7/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.11_for_Xcode_7.dmg).

Comment: I had the same issue when upgrading from El Capitan to Sierra, and the solution was the same: download Sierra's version of the Command Line Tools.

Comment: Same goes for the just-released Mojave. Thanks!

Comment: Same solution for Catalina!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

`sudo xcode-select -r`

in this way it unsets any user-specified developer directory, so that the developer directory  will  be  found  via  the default  search  mechanism.

Comment: This worked for me. [above error occured after upgrading to Catalina from Mojave]

Answer (score 3):

If you have Catalina and Xcode 11 and you have this problem, then go to Xcode Preferences and select Location tab, check that the Command Line tool dropdown has Xcode 11.0 selected. If Xcode 11 is not there then you need to download and install Command-line tools for Xcode 11 here (choose the correct Beta)

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=command%20line%20tools

Comment: Opening Xcode, letting update some components and then making the "Command Line tool dropdown" change suggested here fixed the problem for me.