# How to install Apache Airflow on Python3.7.4 on Mac using Pyenv virtualenv

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, macos, airflow, pyenv

I'm working on Mac Catalina with Pyenv with the goal to install apache-airflow[all]. I'm failing and specifically with apache-airflow[mysql]
here is my recipe:

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.7.4 test
pyenv activate  test
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install Cython

pip install 'apache-airflow[mysql]'
pip install 'apache-airflow[all]'
```

I've tried lots of different stack overflow remedies to install apache-airflow[mysql] including

```
brew upgrade mysql
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

How do I install MYSQL client?
How do I install the complete apache airflow on the virtualenv?

here is the error using pyenv virtualenv

```
(tst) ➜  ~ python -V
Python 3.7.4
(tst) ➜  ~ pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached     https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/97/7326248ac8d5049968bf4ec708a5d3d4806e412a42e74160d7f266a3e03a/mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Users/gideonbar/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/envs/tst/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/t_/ccp4hjg92rzbpjrc4d3cnpm00000gn/T/pip-install-dy9_xr4y/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/t_/ccp4hjg92rzbpjrc4d3cnpm00000gn/T/pip-install-dy9_xr4y/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/t_/ccp4hjg92rzbpjrc4d3cnpm00000gn/T/pip-record-pdn28c7j/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/gideonbar/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/envs/tst/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient
     cwd: /private/var/folders/t_/ccp4hjg92rzbpjrc4d3cnpm00000gn/T/pip-install-dy9_xr4y/mysqlclient/
Complete output (30 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.18_1/include/mysql -I/Users/gideonbar/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/envs/tst/include -I/Users/gideonbar/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/gideonbar/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/gideonbar/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.18_1/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/gideonbar/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/envs/tst/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/t_/ccp4hjg92rzbpjrc4d3cnpm00000gn/T/pip-install-dy9_xr4y/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/t_/ccp4hjg92rzbpjrc4d3cnpm00000gn/T/pip-install-dy9_xr4y/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/t_/ccp4hjg92rzbpjrc4d3cnpm00000gn/T/pip-record-pdn28c7j/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/gideonbar/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/envs/tst/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
(tst) ➜  ~
```

I tried following this link

https://github.com/JudgeGirl/Judge-sender/issues/4

```
brew install mysql # install mysql
brew unlink mysql
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

# in ~/.zshrc update path and set the mysql bin folder to path

```
MYSQL_VER=8.0.18_1
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/$MYSQL_VER/bin:$PATH
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/$MYSQL_VER/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/mysql-client/8.0.18/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib # create symlink
```

in terminal:

```
pyenv activate tst
pip install mysqlclient # install mysql-client finally
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting following error while installing airflow in mac 
*[Invalid active developer path error after upgrading to El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896524/invalid-active-developer-path-error-after-upgrading-to-el-capitan)*

Try following to fix the dependency

`xcode-select --install`

To install apache airflow

`pip install apache-airflow`

Comment: What's the error you are getting ? 
Checkout this.
https://github.com/JudgeGirl/Judge-sender/issues/4