# Fatal Error in R when using tcltk::tkentry

Tags: r, tcltk, tkentry

I recently upgraded my R to 4.0.1 from 3.4.1 because I needed to use the TSP package and hadn't updated R in a while. TSP only requires greater than 3.5.0 but I figured I would install the latest version, right?

Now, I'm trying to run code I use daily for the past several years but am getting a fatal error in both R Studio and the R console. It uses the tcltk library to store username and password, which is crucial as I pull in SQL data from our server to utilize in my code. I don't want to store my credentials in the code, and it's a hassle as our passwords change monthly.

I've tried looking at other questions, such as [Fatal Error After Upgrading R / R Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053682/fatal-error-after-upgrading-r-r-studio) but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Here's my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.1 tools_4.0.1
```

I suspect that `tcltk::tkentry` is the issue, as I went line by line and that's what causes the fatal error.

Here's my function:

```
getLoginDetails <- function(){
  ## Based on code by Barry Rowlingson
  ## http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/tkentry-that-exits-after-RETURN-tt854721.html#none
  require(tcltk)
  tt <- tktoplevel()
  tkwm.title(tt, "Get login details")
  Name <- tclVar("Login ID")
  Password <- tclVar("Password")
  entry.Name <- tkentry(tt,width="20", textvariable=Name)
  entry.Password <- tkentry(tt, width="20", show="*", 
                            textvariable=Password)
  tkgrid(tklabel(tt, text="Please enter your login details."))
  tkgrid(entry.Name)
  tkgrid(entry.Password)

  OnOK <- function()
  { 
    tkdestroy(tt) 
  }
  OK.but <-tkbutton(tt,text=" OK ", command=OnOK)
  tkbind(entry.Password, "<Return>", OnOK)
  tkgrid(OK.but)
  tkfocus(tt)
  tkwait.window(tt)

  invisible(c(loginID=tclvalue(Name), password=tclvalue(Password)))
}
credentials <- getLoginDetails()
```

The package loads correctly and `capabilities("tcltk")` comes back as `TRUE`.

The empty `tktoplevel()` will load:

[image]

But then this error message pops up and R Studio aborts:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated! I need this `getLoginDetails` function for my daily work activities.

If someone has an alternative, I would be open to that, too.

Cheers!

Comment: Maybe verify that `tt` is of the expected class & the contents are valid?   Try running some other "TKwidgets" functions with your `tt` to see if it's only `tkentry` which crashes.  And verify the value of `Name`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, ```tktoplevel()```, ```tclVar```, ```tkwm.title``` all work properly. ```Name``` isn't able to be stored. That's where the crash occurs.

Comment: @scopeland those aren't relevant.  I mean any other functions listed at `?TkWidgets`

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with TclTk.  Rcmdr won't run in R-4.0.1 but runs OK in R-4.0.0

My home-brew package won't load if Tcltk functionality is called.

Answer (score 0):

The [release notes for R 4.0.2](http://cran.stat.auckland.ac.nz/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-4.0.2.html) report that the bug has been fixed in that version:

> Using tcltk widgets no longer crashes R on Windows.