# Cannot install accumulation-tree

Tags: python

Why do I always get this error when I try to install accumulation-tree? I need this for optbinning. A similar package would also be a solution.

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/elisaderoo/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools,     tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/yc/59hh1mg16c90lpnfsfvwcnf80000gn/T/pip-install-29thp5kc/accumulation-tree/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/yc/59hh1mg16c90lpnfsfvwcnf80000gn/T/pip-install-29thp5kc/accumulation-tree/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/yc/59hh1mg16c90lpnfsfvwcnf80000gn/T/pip-wheel-4djg7a0d
       cwd: /private/var/folders/yc/59hh1mg16c90lpnfsfvwcnf80000gn/T/pip-install-29thp5kc/accumulation-tree/
  Complete output (19 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/accumulation_tree
  copying accumulation_tree/treeslice.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/accumulation_tree
  copying accumulation_tree/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/accumulation_tree
  copying accumulation_tree/abctree.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/accumulation_tree
  running build_ext
  cythoning accumulation_tree/accumulation_tree.pyx to accumulation_tree/accumulation_tree.c
  /Users/elisaderoo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /private/var/folders/yc/59hh1mg16c90lpnfsfvwcnf80000gn/T/pip-install-29thp5kc/accumulation-tree/accumulation_tree/accumulation_tree.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  building 'accumulation_tree.accumulation_tree' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/accumulation_tree
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/elisaderoo/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/elisaderoo/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/elisaderoo/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c accumulation_tree/accumulation_tree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-  3.8/accumulation_tree/accumulation_tree.o
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools),    missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
     ----------------------------------------
     ERROR: Failed building wheel for accumulation-tree
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error might be due to not having Cython installed. Alternatively, you can clone the repository from GitHub, remove the dependency tdigest from the list of install_requires in setup.py, and install from the source using python setup.py install.

Answer (score 0):

Try running (in a terminal window)

`xcode-select –install`

(and clicking through dialog)

If that doesn't work try:

`sudo xcode-select --reset`

Several links show this problem in other contexts (e.g.)

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/673827

[Fatal Error (invalid active developer path ) After Upgrading R / R Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053682/fatal-error-invalid-active-developer-path-after-upgrading-r-r-studio)

Answer (score 0):

you may not have installed `gfortran`

first try to install it

```
sudo apt install gfortran
```