# MacOS Sierra broke my git, oh noes - Applicable to Sierra, High Sierra, and Mojave

Tags: macos-sierra

I upgraded to MacOS Sierra today and went to my repo like normal but none of the git commands work, in fact my machine doesn't recognize that I have git installed. help?

I found [this article](https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2015/10/01/how-i-got-el-capitain-working-with-my-developer-tools/) but it seems a little elaborate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command Line Tools bash (git) not working - macOS Sierra final release candidate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484218/command-line-tools-bash-git-not-working-macos-sierra-final-release-candidate)

Comment: shoot I didn't see that one when I was searching

Comment: Also I think this is helpful specifically because it addresses upgrading to Sierra OS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command Line Tools not working - OS X El Capitan/macOS Sierra/macOS High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893412/command-line-tools-not-working-os-x-el-capitan-macos-sierra-macos-high-sierra)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

All that is a little elaborate, for many cases all you need to do is reinstall xcode developer tools.

Open Terminal or iTerm and Run this:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: I've just upgraded to High Sierra and the solution is still valid.

Comment: yupp, just upgraded to High Sierra and problem was resolved.