# Bower Install Jquery error

Tags: bower-install

Can someone help me with the following error displayed below. I 'am currently trying to install jquery using bower install jquery. When performing the command I get the following.

```
bower jquery#*              not-cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#*
bower jquery#*                 resolve https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#*
bower jquery#*                 ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git", exit code of #1 xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

Additional error details:
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command Line Tools not working - OS X El Capitan/ macOS-sierra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893412/command-line-tools-not-working-os-x-el-capitan-macos-sierra)

Comment: Thanks you! Using the xcode-select --install solved it.