# An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, github, rubygems

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

make failed, exit code 1

I know this has already been posted but i have tried bundle update, bundle install and putting the gem file in my gem file and bundle install but nothing works from the other answers.

ideas?

Answer (score 25):

Running "bundle update" worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

You can try `bundle update && bundle install`.
More on this [here](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4462).

Answer (score 11):

A safer approach can be: 
`bundle update json` 
`bundle install`

Comment: This answer was already posted at least once. How is your solution any different? What makes it "safer"?

Answer (score 4):

Remove your old Gemfile.lock file and run bundle again. A newer version of json should be installed.

Answer (score 3):

Run the following in terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893412/command-line-tools-not-working-os-x-el-capitan-macos-sierra/32894314#32894314)

Answer (score 1):

With Ruby 2.4.4, use Backup version 5.0.0.beta.1.

gem install backup -v5.0.0.beta.1

This solved the issue for me