# Upgrading Mac Os, now Clion is not working ask to me configuration path is not correct

Tags: c++, clion, macos-sierra, jetbrains-ide

Please help to solve this problem
Mac Version: MacOS Sierra 10.12.1
cLion: Version 1.1

> Error:The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple
>   test program. It fails with the following output: Change Dir:
>   /Users/macbook/Library/Caches/clion11/cmake/generated/8cb5a468/8cb5a468/**default**/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>   Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_be548/fast" xcrun: error:
>   invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools),
>   missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
>   CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems related to the fact that command line tools need to be updated after OS update. Check solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893412/command-line-tools-not-working-os-x-el-capitan-macos-sierra).