# Can't Install Python Module "Thinx" (Mac)

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to install the module `thinkx` by typing

`pip install thinkx`in the terminal (as described [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=thinkx&:action=display)). However, the module is not installed and it keeps showing `xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`, `error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1`, and `Failed building wheel for subprocess32`. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893412/command-line-tools-not-working-os-x-el-capitan-macos-sierra

Comment: It totally works. Thanks!