# Unable to build Go application after Mac update

Tags: xcode, macos, go

I just updated to High Sierra and now I can't build any GoLang Applications. I get the following error:

```
> # command-line-arguments
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

I have tried

```
xcode-select --install
```

and

```
xcode-select --reset
```

But neither have worked, has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Could you try reinstalling with brew?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered this after upgrade to High Sierra and addressed it with

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Comment: There are some other options at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893412/command-line-tools-not-working-os-x-el-capitan-macos-sierra-macos-high-sierra/32894314#32894314

That's where I got my solution from