# installing Perl modules Statistics::Multtest

Tags: perl, cpan

I need to install:

```
cpan Statistics::Multtest
cpan Text::NSP::Measures::2D::Fisher::twotailed
```

The response is the next:

```
Warning: Prerequisite 'List::Vectorize => 1.00' for 'JOKERGOO/Statistics-Multtest-0.14.tar.gz' failed when processing 'JOKERGOO/List-Vectorize-1.05.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  JOKERGOO/Statistics-Multtest-0.14.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Can you help me? I don not know what to do?

Comment: Did you read the error message? You seem to be missing a tool called `xcrun` that the build process needs.

Comment: Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32894314/2375207

Comment: I hope you´re trying to run this on Mac! If you are, just install xcode! Otherwise I guess you can´t run this on Linux nor Windows until I know.