# I opened Terminal on my MacBook Pro and this error message appeared

Tags: swift, terminal

My Terminal had a fault, and I fixed it, but now I have an issue. When I type in Swift, an error message appears. Below this paragraph is what happened when i typed Swift. If anyone can help me, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!!!

> Last login: Wed Jan 31 16:20:34 on ttys000 Groshvins-MBP:~ P.W$ swift
>
> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path
>   (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun Groshvins-MBP:~ P.W$

(P.S I placed a paragraph to make it easier)

Comment: Have you tried `xcode-select`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command Line Tools not working - OS X El Capitan/macOS Sierra/macOS High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893412/command-line-tools-not-working-os-x-el-capitan-macos-sierra-macos-high-sierra)

Comment: Samah no I didn't, so how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google would have given you tons of results!

To fix it, Open terminal and fire following command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

That should help you.

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32894314/2231063), [here](https://rehmat.works/xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-fix-on-macos-high-sierra/)