# WebStorm isn't allowing me to put a project on GitHub

Tags: webstorm

So I'm using WebStorm and trying to put a project on GitHub, but every time I select "Share Project on GitHub" from the VCS menu, I get the following error message:

> Errors while executing git --version. exitCode=1 errors: xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

Now, at the time of writing this I'm not even positive that I linked my WebStorm to a GitHub account. Would this message be related to that if I don't? If so, where would I go to check if I linked it?

Answer (score 0):

Please open try running

`xcode-select --install`

In your OS terminal - this will download and install xcode developer tools and fix the problem. The problem likely is that one needs to explicitly agree to the license agreement.

see [Command Line Tools not working - OS X El Capitan/macOS Sierra/macOS High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893412/command-line-tools-not-working-os-x-el-capitan-macos-sierra-macos-high-sierra/32894314#32894314):