# tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

Tags: xcode, npm

This is very much a duplicate of [xcode-select active developer directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error) except none of those solutions worked for me.

```
$ sudo xcode-select --reset
$ sudo xcodebuild -license accept                                  
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
$ sudo xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

I don't even have xcode on my machine.

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64216275/5003820

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The fix for me here was that my [ XCode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools ] dropdown was empty. No idea why. But after clicking it and selecting the only available option my "*active developer directory*" error finally went away.

Mac Os 12.3.1 | Date: 5/4/22

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Such a trivialty... completely lacking feedback... I can now use the opendiff command-line on my brand new machine. There's a dark spot in the transparency and you helped me through it.

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem because Xcode was installed in my user application directory (~/Applications) instead of /Applications.  From the Github link above figured out I needed to run:

```
sudo xcode-select -s ~/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

(note the tilde).  After this everything worked.

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking for a simple command that can fix this, and your xcode is installed in the default location (`/Applications/Xcode.app`), you can fix this with this command:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 3):

I had  "xcode-select active developer directory error" too when installing Xcode beta. In your case you don't even need full Xcode, command line tools should work fine. Read this Github [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/569)

Answer (score -3):

This error completely contradicts that setting the path to /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools is the workaround for the latest XCode/MacOS combo failing to find the command line tool commands under /Application/Xcode.App/ with the default path setting.