# I installed vcpkg-master for visual studio code and install their package and after that only my Clion stopped working

Tags: c, cmake, clion

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /Users/kushthakker/CLionProjects/dog_age
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
CMake Error at /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.
```

It fails with the following output:

```
Change Dir: /Users/kushthakker/CLionProjects/dog_age/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_dced2/fast && xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Comment: You have definitely checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893412/command-line-tools-not-working-os-x-el-capitan-sierra-high-sierra-mojave) about the same error message, haven't you?