# How do I verify from bash that xcode command line tools are already installed or not?

Tags: xcode, macos

I am looking for a bash sequence that would tell me if xcode command line tools are installed or not (exit code 0 if they are, something different if not).

Comment: The Yosemite update in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371925/how-to-check-if-command-line-tools-is-installed) seems to work also for El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if Xcode Command Line Tools are installed by entering on Terminal:

```
xcode-select -p
```

To install them, simply run:

```
xcode-select --install
```