# Install Command Line Developer Tools: can't install the software because it is not currently available from the software update server

Tags: xcode, macos, command-line, xcode11

I'm having a problem installing the Command Line Developer Tools with `xcode-select --install` using Xcode 11 beta and on Mac Mojave 10.14.5.

The download starts happening and then gets promptly stopped with a message stating:

> Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the software update server.

I've looked this up and all the threads that I find all have dead links to download the command line tools:

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53078282/3325126)

[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19908327/3325126)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode is not currently available from the Software Update server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907576/xcode-is-not-currently-available-from-the-software-update-server)

Answer (score 12):

I was able to download the command line tools directly from the Downloads page on the Apple Developer site: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=command%20line%20tools

Note you'll need to login with an iCloud account to access it.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT
after some pcaping and other dumbness i finally poked around in the xcode gui-- go to Open Developer Tools > More Developer Tools
it will launch a webpage behind the dev portal where you can dl the dmg

---

im guessing their repos are down. im getting the same. picked a bad day to try and installl gcc from brew

Comment: After a lot of messing about this is the only thing that worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these answers worked for me, I later found the solution was my installation was done improperly the first time. I ran these commands and got the command line working.

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```