# Installing command line developer tools for Xcode 12.2

Tags: swift, xcode, macos-catalina

I need to install the command line developer tools for Xcode 12.2 on a fresh upgrade to macOS Catalina.

Whether I install command line developer tools by clicking `Install` when I get:

[image: Swift requires the command line developer tools]

after typing `swift` in a Terminal window, or I install by
[downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53078282/704972) `Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_12.2.dmg` from
[developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=command%20line%20tools)

[image: Download/install Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_12.2.dmg]

I still get:

```
:~/ > swift
xcodebuild: error: SDK "macosx10.14" cannot be located.
swift: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk macosx10.14 -find swift 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 16384: (null) (errno=No such file or directory)
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'swift', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
```

Suggestions?

Comment: What happened on SO? Granted, the question lacks profundity. But weren't questions about tools quite ok over here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you didn't install the PKG that lives on the DMG that you downloaded. But if you did, it sounds like you need to add this step:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Comment: Great! That does it. Now before the `Welcome .. ` message and the prompt `1>`, I get `swift: error: SDK "macosx10.14" cannot be located`, `<unknown>:0: warning: no such SDK: 'macosx10.14'`, but that's a good start. And indeed in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs` I have `MacOSX.sdk -> MacOSX11.0.sdk`, `MacOSX10.15.sdk`, and `MacOSX11.0.sdk`, but no `MacOSX14.0.sdk`. Could it be that Xcode 12.2 is expecting me to be on Big Sur (10.15)?

Comment: No. Xcode 12.2 doesn't require Big Sur.

Comment: if my answer works for you, may i ask that you 'select' it?

Comment: This last remaining problem is a tricky one, and it's been going on https://trac.macports.org/ticket/59837 since Mojave. Speculation: those who start from a clean macOS have no issues, but those who have multiple ancient SDKs inherited through Time Machine (or similar) in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs have this problem when we install an Xcode that's been developed for an OS version higher than the one we have just upgraded to.